# How to properly test EntityFramework, Repository pattern and Business logic w/ complex objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have a database with a somewhat complex design, and therefore the issue is complex too.

I communicate with this database through Entity Framework. My codebase looks like this:

1. Data layer: Entity Framework, DbContext, Data models.
2. Repository layer: Basic CRUD operation providers for the models.
3. Logic layer: Business logic.
4. Web API layer: Controllers to communicate with the service.
5. Test layer: Do Business logic unit tests.

I am in the process to write unit tests and I don't know how to write them properly, or if my business logic layer is just bad... In college, they thought me to do it this way, but I think I might misunderstood the principle behind this pattern...

In my business logic method, I pass a domain object as a parameter, and I use LINQ to 'query' the database to find the needed result. Every method uses the 'queries' as logic. So it's heavily dependent on the query.
For example, I need to determine if 2 users are matched with each other or not (like in Tinder)

```
public bool AreTheyMatched(Profile requestor, Profile requested)
        {
            var areTheyMatched = ChatRepository.GetAll().Where(x =>
                   x.Profiles.Contains(requestor) &&
                   x.Profiles.Contains(requested) &&
                   x.SYS_ChatType.Type.ToLower() == "match" &&
                   x.Profiles.Count() == 2).Count() == 1;
            return areTheyMatched;
```

What's considered the best practice here?

- I feel like mocking the query is useless here...
- Also feel like the query should not be part of the logic...
- Mocking the GetAll() method is alright, but since Entity framework generated POCO classes are self-referencing (Chat has Profile list, Profile has Chat entity, and so on...) the set up of mocking would be hard, but possible...
- Should I gather data from the scope of the parameters?
- How can I test the queries to see if they are right at all?
- How can I test business logic at all?

I did the unit tests of validating simple objects while being inserted into the database. That's a no-brainer for me. But this topic's complexity seems to be out of the scope of my current understanding.

Comment: Note, Layer 2) can be omitted without violating consensus best-practices.  An EF DbContext is already your repository layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of chat objects with nested profiles that suits your current test case. For example, a list that actually contains a match of the two profiles. Then mock the repository to return this list and assert that a match was found. For another test case, setup the chat list without a match, and assert that no match was found.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes that's one way. But this is a huge overhead just to set up the test cases properly. Especially if the query is complex enough to travel through deeply nested objects.

Comment: But do you need to setup the whole chain of nested objects? E.g., in this case you only care about profiles and chats. If the profile objects are deeply nested with other objects, but those are not used in the query, can you just omit them?

Comment: You are right. Sounded confusing at first, but I started implementing it. Now everything is starting to click. Everything comes down to setting up the mock correctly. Thanks!